# jquery: can I change a link's href dynamically while on hover?

Tags: jquery, href

Hi I have a slider of images each inside a link

I am trying to change the links' href when on hover as well

Is it possible?

Cheers

```
$('#hm_img').parent().attr('href', arrImgs[i].link);
```

this only work if I hover out can come back

Comment: show some html it will helpful

Comment: I think I didn't put in the right words. I have one link that changes it's href dynamically every 8 sec. if I stay on that link with the mouse and wait for a cycle to change it's href it just remains the same href as when i started hover'ing it ! Does it make more sense?

Answer (score 1):

Try using **`.hover()`**, along with a callback.  Make sure the respective element to be there in `this`.

Here is an sample example.

```
  $('#hm_img').parent().hover(function () {
      $(this).attr("href", "hovered href");  //Note: refer the respective element
  }, function () {
      $(this).attr("href", "back to href");  //Note: refer the respective element
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('get the id of the image').attr('href', 'your new link')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in the img

```
onmouseover="$(this).parent().attr('href',$(this).attr('src'))"
```

Change this part : `$(this).attr('src')` for something to lookup the link in the array. Possible with some attribute on the img refering to position like..

```
onmouseover="$(this).parent().attr('href',arrImgs[$(this).attr('data-imgpos')].link)"
```

or just include link as attribute on `img`.